# Is it ok that reverse DNS for my mail server resolves to www2.domain.com and not domain.com?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, email-server, reverse-dns

I am trying to make sure my mail server is set up correctly. One of the steps is to ensure that reverse DNS works. We email from ...@domain.com. When I test rDNS using nslookup i get:

```
$ nslookup yast.com
Server:     192.168.80.1
Address:    192.168.80.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   domain.com
Address: 1.2.3.4

$ nslookup 1.2.3.4
Server:     192.168.80.1
Address:    192.168.80.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
4.3.2.1.in-addr.arpa    name = www2.domain.com.

Authoritative answers can be found from:
193.156.64.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns3.m5hosting.com.
193.156.64.in-addr.arpa nameserver = ns2.m5hosting.com.
ns3.m5hosting.com   internet address = 209.216.230.5
ns2.m5hosting.com   internet address = 209.216.206.16
```

www2.domain.com is the name of the server (probably can be changed).

**Will mail servers at google, aol, yahoo, etc view this as suspicious?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever the PTR match the @domain part of the mail addresses or not really doesn't matter. The import part is that the PTR record should match the name used during HELO/EHLO, when your SMTP server "introduces" itself.

Answer (score 0):

andol's answer is correct. I can add that when we provisioned your server, we created the PTR record for the first IP address (in your case you have only one IP) to match the hostname of the server. Unless you have changed the email configuration or changed the hostname of the server, you are already set up correctly for the PTR.

If you have made changes to the hostname or to the mail server configuration, just let us know what it is now and we can make a change to the PTR record immediately. We can also update your account info so that the new hostname is reflected in our customer portal and on your monthly bill.

Mike

Comment: I am truly amazed that you picked up that one. That's what i call customer service :) We'll be using m5 exclusively from now on!